# Visualizing density histogram evolving over time

Tags: visualization

The code below visualizes trajectories of equation $e=e-x\langle e,x\rangle$ for Gaussian $x$.

I'm using `ListLinePlot` with `Filling`, but it generates edge artifacts. Any suggestion how to make this diagram smoother? Tried `EdgeForm[]` to no result.

[image]

Related question is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251270/visualizing-changing-histogram-over-time)

```
Clear["Global`*"];

(* Gaussian sampler with diagonal covariance *)
SeedRandom[1, Method -> "MKL"];
SF = StringForm;
gaussianSampler[diag_] := With[{d = Length[diag]},
   Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
    Module[{vals, diagSqrt},
     diagSqrt = Sqrt[diag];
     vals = 
      diagSqrt*# & /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, d}]]]];


(* Generates plot for Gaussian SGD with cov eigenvalues \
1^-p,2^-p,...,d^-p, by using step size a *) 
generatePlot[p_, d_, a_] := Module[{},
   B = 1000;
   numSteps = 100;
   ones = ConstantArray[1., d];
   h = Table[i^-p, {i, 1, d}];
   sampler = gaussianSampler[h];
   W0 = sampler[B];
   
   step[w_, x_] = w - a x x . w;
   batchStep[W_] := MapThread[step, {W, sampler[B]}];
   traj = NestList[batchStep, W0, numSteps]; (* numSteps x B x d *)
   
   errorNorms2 = Total[traj*traj, {3}]; (* numSteps x B *)
   numQuantiles = 100;
   compress[l_] := Quantile[l, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/numQuantiles];
   
   meanPlot = 
    ListLinePlot[Total[errorNorms2, {2}]/B, ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
      PlotLegends -> {"mean"}];
   filling = 
    Table[i -> {numQuantiles + 2 - i}, {i, 1, numQuantiles/2}];
   distPlot = 
    ListLinePlot[Transpose[compress /@ errorNorms2], 
     ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Filling -> filling, 
     FillingStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[.1], EdgeForm[]], 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Thin]}];
   
   Show[distPlot, meanPlot, 
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "||e\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(||\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
    PlotLabel -> SF["e=e-x<e,x>", d], ImageSize -> Large]
   
   ];

p = 1;
d = 1;
a = 2.4212495210368360429927801314282259331288428340678678473778384243\
45397835692066559296652232682365322;
generatePlot[p, d, a]
```

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-gaussian-convergence.nb)

Comment: Are you looking for `PlotStyle->None`? Of not, what exactly do you mean by "edge artifacts"?

Comment: Yes, `PlotStyle->None` seems to be what I needed